# Setting the Prize to be won before spinning in Winwheel.js

Tags: javascript

I referred [Winwheel.js](http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/docs) and tried to set the prize before the spin. Spin and other functions are working fine. But I want to stop the spin in first segments as always. I tried the [documentation](http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/docs/tut14_setting_the_prize). But it didn't work. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
var theWheel = new Winwheel({
    'numSegments': 3,
    'outerRadius': 0,
    'drawMode': 'image',
    'segments': [{
            'text': 'Prize 1'
                }, {
            'text': 'Prize 2'
                }, {
            'text': 'Prize 3'
                }
            ],
    'animation':
    {
        'type': 'spinToStop',
        'duration': 5,
        'spins': 8,
        'callbackFinished': alertPrize,
        'callbackSound': playSound
    }
});
var audio = new Audio('./assets/img/tick.mp3');
function playSound() {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
}
var loadedImg = new Image();
loadedImg.onload = function () {
    theWheel.wheelImage = loadedImg;
    theWheel.draw();
}
loadedImg.src = "./assets/img/planes.png";
var wheelPower = 0;
var wheelSpinning = false;
function startSpin() {
    if (wheelSpinning == false) {
        theWheel.animation.spins = 5;
        $("#spin-form input").prop('disabled', true);
        theWheel.startAnimation();
        wheelSpinning = true;
    }
}
function calculatePrize() {
    var stopAt = theWheel.getRandomForSegment(1);
    theWheel.animation.stopAngle = stopAt;
    theWheel.startAnimation();
}
function alertPrize(indicatedSegment) {
   alert("The wheel stopped on " + indicatedSegment.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I forgot to call the `calculatePrize` function when the spin button clicked. Now it's working fine :)

```
function startSpin() {
    if (wheelSpinning == false) {
        calculatePrize();
        theWheel.animation.spins = 5;
        $("#spin-form input").prop('disabled', true);
        theWheel.startAnimation();
        wheelSpinning = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for sharing. can you please make jsfiddle for this so that anyone can play with it.One more thing do you any idea how can we use this in Reactjs?